# Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports javac

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am attempting to compile a "Hello World" program in Java 8 update 333. When I attempt to compile it, this happens:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports javac.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

`java -version`:

```
java version "1.8.0_333"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_333-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.333-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What command are you using to try and compile?

Comment: @khelwood `javac Main.java`

Comment: You probably installed a JRE (Java Runtime Environment) rather than a JDK (Java Development Kit). You need a JDK to be able to compile.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Aha, it IS a JRE...

Comment: Good, it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed a JRE (Java Runtime Environment) rather than a JDK (Java Development Kit). You need a JDK to be able to compile.

(Thanks go to [RealSkeptic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125191/realskeptic) for the answer - see above.)